# Saving/exporting full resolution map with contours and elevation data from QGIS

Tags: qgis, export

Brand new to QGIS. I just spent 3 hours figuring how to create the exact map I needed from the orthomosaic maps I finished rendering with WebODM.

Everything is good, except that I need to save the map I have created as an image for my client.

I have tried everything I have found online, but I still am not able to save the map exactly how I need it onto an image.

When in QGIS I can zoom into the map, and the contours as well as the elevation data will become more and more detailed. If I zoom out, then the elevation data is less detailed.

Well, that's exactly what I need to do.

I need to save this map as an image, in which when I open the image, I see the entirety of the map. And I want to be able to zoom in and see down to the most detailed elevation data for each contour line.

I have tried exporting as image, as PDF, as DXF, I have tried saving as the layers, and so on...but nothing is giving me what I need.

The closest thing is when I export as image and I save it as a 1:1 scale, the saved image shows the most detailed view, but then it only saves a tiny little part of the map! I need to save the entire map with 1:1 scale detail.

How in the world do I do that?

Comment: Please provide more details on how you export your map, as well as the extent of the map, the number of layers, and how many terrabyte of storage you are willing to provide.

Comment: The closest output to match your QGIS project would be to export to pdf with the always export as vector option checked and the simplify geometries unchecked.  I'd create a GeoPDF too in case you have raster elements in your map.  If you only can use full rasters it is much harder.  You might try exporting multiple maps to tif at different scales and then use the raster-miscellaneous-build overviews to put them together, or export to tif at a very high resolution ( and size) and then use the translate format option to create a jpeg 2000 which will create its own pyramids.

Comment: You can also see if an export to SVG will be useful but you will get a warning it often doesn't work and that's because if often doesn't work as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! And thank you John!! You were right, the pdf option was what worked. I kept playing with it and realized the reason why the map kept getting cut off was due to the "Extent" selection, it said CURRENT MAP VIEW" and once I changed the Layer to the select the map itself, then the extent because the entire map and Viola! I then just adjusted the scale to 1:56 and the output size adjusted automatically, i just exported and it's exactly what I needed! It's just a bit large, 58megabytes so I'll need so send it via drop box. But that's no problem. Thank you Soo much again!!